# Android - squished icon in actionbar after support library update

Tags: java, android

I want to have a checkmark icon in the actionbar. 
The code I'm using is:

In menu_actionbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title=""
        android:id="@+id/action_check"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white_48dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

In the activity:

```
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_actionbar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here's what it's supposed to look like, and how it has looked for a while until some recent support library update (not sure which one exactly): [correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0rxS.png)

Here's what it looks like on the device now: [incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOBQN.png)

Comment: Having the same issue at the moment.  Just updated code to use v7:26.0.0 support libs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squashed icons in toolbar after change to Android SDK 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340740/squashed-icons-in-toolbar-after-change-to-android-sdk-26)