# Squashed icons in toolbar after change to Android SDK 26

Tags: java, android, xml

After changing my app from compiling/targeting SDK v25 to SDK v26, all of the menu icons in my app's toolbar are now squashed/squished/stretched.

Here's the relevant layout code:

```
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

                <br.com.mauker.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here's a menu that squishes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/advanced_search"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="@string/advanced_search"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Here's another menu that squishes (they all do):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/add_photo"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="@string/add_photo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_white_48dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

[How it looks on SDK v25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyGrg.png)

[How it looks on SDK v26](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSXIX.png)

Comment: You should post your menu.xml file

Comment: Sure thing, done.

Comment: @DChiuch, you may accept my answer

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64207386  not fixed in 26.0.1 yet, waiting for next release :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The matter is that the icon size is bigger then the expected. Obviously the scaling mechanism has changed in SDK 26 and now it leads to this UI bug. Make sure the toolbar icon resources are provided in the following sizes.

**Updated:**

Since the Toolbar min height `abc_action_bar_default_height_material` is `56dp` and `abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material` is `16dp`, the toolbar icons are meant to be with a min size of `24dp` in mdpi:

```
drawable-mdpi - 24 x 24 px
drawable-hdpi - 36 x 36 px
drawable-xhdpi - 48 x 48 px
drawable-xxhdpi - 72 x 72 px
drawable-xxxhdpi - 96 x 96 px
```

Comment: Shouldn't they be 24dp on mdpi?

Comment: Thanks, you're right, the new SDK has problems downscaling images. Using a correct sized image (starting at 24px) worked with no problems.

Comment: In actual fact 32 px in mdpi also works fine without the scaling bug, but having in mind the min height of the toolbar, you are right. So I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue with version 26.0.0 of the appcompat-v7 support library. Updating to 26.0.2 fixed it :)

See here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64207386

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate different drawable icons and place in respective folder to work. You can use [this link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html) to generate different size icons.