# Icons look flat in action bar

Tags: android-studio, android-8.0-oreo

I've recently "upgraded" my android project to SDK version 26, and now the icons in my app bar look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMPEd.png) (run on Android 6.0), although the icon itself looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abgsB.png). I've got no idea why this is happening, I didn't change anything in the java or xml code that seems to be related to this.
I would be very happy if someone posted a solution to this as this could be a bigger problem once Android 8 is released.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.jamesbeans.quadrasolve"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "digit1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.1'
}
```

relevant part of activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/maintoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="QuadraSolve"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />
```

relevant part of MainActivity.java:

```
Toolbar maintoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.maintoolbar);
setSupportActionBar(maintoolbar);
```

...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

mainmenu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_history"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_history_48px"
        android:title="@string/history"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: desired behavior: icon looking normal, specific problem: icon looks distorted after upgrading sdk version, code: added necessary code

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of your <item> attribute?

Comment: I don't think there is a height attribute, at least I can't find one [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

Comment: i have same problem in support:26.0.1 too. any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue currently, but no idea how to fix it directly. Made tests with 25.0.2 and 26.0.1, got the issue only for 26.0.1 for a custom vector drawable. My temporary solution is to use a Vector Asset provided by Google via Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue and stumbled across this answer which seems to have fixed the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45344964/4579919

> The matter is that the icon size is bigger then the expected. Obviously the scaling mechanism has changed in SDK 26 and now it leads to this UI bug. Make sure the toolbar icon resources are provided in the following sizes.